# How can I dynamically update postData from a navigation button in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with a custom navigation button that looks like this:

[image]

The button to the left of the refresh button is my custom button. I am successful in having it execute a `$('#bom').trigger('reloadGrid');` but I need to know on the server which button initiated the request. I would like to add the button name to postData. I tried:

```
$("#bom").jqGrid({postData:{jqgAction:"release"}});
$("#bom").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

But that does not add the extra field to the request string. `postData` already has some values in it, and those are unaffected as I see them in the request. I just need to be able to dynamically add an additional field, and don't know how to insert the additional values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Instead of using:

```
$("#bom").jqGrid({postData:{jqgAction:"release"}});
```

to update `postData`, I can use:

```
this.p.postData.jqgAction="release";
```

Comment: Using the standard API you can do the following: `$("#bom").jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData").jqgAction = "release";`

Comment: Is there a place that standard APIs like this are documented?

Comment: `getGridParam` allow to get the reference to any parameter/option of jqGrid. The list of options is described in [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) or [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1089-L1412)